# $\lim_n x_n = \lim_n y_n =A$, then $\lim_n z_n = A$

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose that $\lim_n x_n = \lim_n y_n =A$ and $z_n$ is determined by flipping a coin as

$z_n = 
\begin{cases}
x_n & \text{if the nth flip of the coin is heads;}\\
y_n & \text{if the nth flip of the coin is tails.}
\end{cases}
$

Prove $\lim_n z_n = A$.

My attempt was,

Suppose that $x_n\leq y_n\leq z_n$ for all n. Then subtracting n gives us $0\leq z_n−x_n \leq y_n−x_n$ for all n. Since $(x_n) → A$ and $(z_n) → A$, it implies that $(y_n −x_n)$ converges to $A-A = 0$. Therefore what we just proved implies that $(z_n − x_n) → 0$. Which implies that $(z_n − x_n + x_n)$ converges to A. Hence $(z_n) = (z_n − x_n + x_n)$ converges to A, as desired.

I am unsure if this is correct.

Comment: What does $\lim_n$ mean?

Comment: Why the down votes?

Comment: @DiegoMath Because no context

Comment: @DiegoMath people expect to see some of OP's contributions to the problem, not just a statement. Context would help too

Comment: Nick, what you have tried?

Comment: @DiegoMath I have edited my question to include my attempt. I am unsure if it is correct.

Comment: @Nicky When you suppose $x_n\leq y_n\leq z_n$, you only answer a particular case of the problem. The heart of the problem is realize that both $x_n$ and $y_n$ are close to $A$ when  $n$ goes to infinity. Look the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

To prove that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}z_n=A$$
we have to show that, for $\varepsilon>0$, there exists $n_0$ such that, for all $n>n_0$ we have $|z_n-A|<\varepsilon$.

Note that $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=\lim_{n\to\infty}y_n=A$, therefore, given $\varepsilon>0$, there exist $n_1,n_2$ such that
$$|x_n-A|<\varepsilon,\quad\forall\ n>n_1$$
and
$$|y_n-A|<\varepsilon,\quad\forall\ n>n_2.$$
Set $n_0=\max\{n_1,n_2\}$, then is still valid:
$$|x_n-A|<\varepsilon,\quad\forall\ n>n_0$$
and
$$|y_n-A|<\varepsilon,\quad\forall\ n>n_0.$$
Hence, for $n>n_0$ we have two cases:

> If the $n$th flip is head:
>   $$|z_n-A|=|x_n-A|<\varepsilon.$$
>
> If the $n$th flip is tail:
>   $$|z_n-A|=|y_n-A|<\varepsilon.$$

Thus, in both cases, given $\epsilon>0$, for all $n>n_0$ we have
$$|z_n-A|<\varepsilon.$$
Finally, we can conclude
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}z_n=A.$$